# Adding numbers inside a span tag in nav menu

Tags: menus, jquery, variables

I am working on a wordpress navigation menu and trying to simlpy (of course, dynamically) add number inside a span tag for each menu li item.

So I created a "top menu" using the wordpress custom menu function
then I used a simple jquery function to add a "span" tag inside each  tag like so:

```
$("#top .menu ul li a").prepend("<span></span>");
```

This generated the following HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href=""><span></span>Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span></span>Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span></span>Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span></span>Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thats exactly what I want as step #1
Now, what I am trying to get is a simple jquery function which will dynamically add a following number inside each divs maybe using a variable or something.
The out put needs to be:

```
<ul>
<li><a href=""><span>1</span>Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>2</span>Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>3</span>Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>4</span>Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

etc.. etc..

should be a very simple jquery function. just can't find it.
any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#top .menu ul li").each(function(i, el) {
    $(this).children('a').prepend("<span>" + (i+1) + "</span>");
});
```

or much better

```
$("#top2 .menu ul li").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children('a').prepend("<span>" + ($this.index()+1) + "</span>");
});
```

check this out for the difference...
http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/aAYCt/

Answer (score 0):

You should need something like that

```
var menuIndex = 0; 
jQuery('#top .menu ul li a span').each(function(){ 
    jQuery(this).html(++menuIndex); 
});
```

Anyway, you could do it in once, by creating and filling the span at the same time.

Comment: If you like the answer, could you vote it up? I agree Reigel's one is more complete, so it's his answer the one that should be accepted, but you can vote more than one ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function fill_numbers_in_span() {
  jQuery("#top .menu ul li a").each(function(index){
    jQuery(this).prepend("<span></span>").find('span').text(index+1);
  });
}
```

This function will do the trick. It prepends `span` as well as adds the correct index. Just make sure that the selector `"#top .menu ul li a"` is correct.

Comment: Great @Mridul Aggarwal Thanks! I will try that out